# Rock Paper Scissors Game issue with the Reflect player always play none

Tags: python, python-3.x

The issue is with the Reflect player always play none and I don't know why

```
import random

moves = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']


class Player:
    def move(self):
        return 'rock'
```

This class selects a random move choice

```
class Reflect(Player):
    def __init__(self):

        Player.__init__(self)
        self.learn_move = None
```

This Class cycles through the moves list starting at rock

```
class Human(Player):
    def move(self):
        while True:
            self.user_input = input("Choose rock, paper, scissors?")
            if self.user_input in moves:
                break
        return self.user_input
```

This class requests a human player to make a selection

```
class Game:
    def __init__(self, p1, p2):
        self.p1 = p1
        self.p2 = p2
        self.p1_score = 0
        self.p2_score = 0
```

This class starts the game prints information and calls the round class and score

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    game = Game(Human(), Reflect())
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not calling the super class correctly, instead you're trying to call a class method

```
Player.__init__(self)
```

should be

```
super().__init__()
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
class Reflect(Player):
     def __init__(self):
        Player.__init__(self)
        self.their_move = None

    def play(self):
        if self.their_move is None:
            return Player.play(self)
        return self.last_opponent_move
```